# can I start processing XML from shell script?

Tags: xml, shell, ubuntu-16.04, laravel-artisan

I start an sh script with crontab to create an xml file ("MyXML") with "MyApp.exe" using config files from "SpecificDirectory":

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/MyDirectory
mono MyApp.exe ./SpecificDirectory
```

And then there is another cron tab processing the MyXML file into the database.

```
1 7 * * * php /var/www/html/artisan xml:process MyXML >> /var/log/xml-process.log 2>&1
```

Can I add that artisan xml process to the shell script, so it is not executed by the crontab, but immediately after the exe finished creating MyXML?

If yes, how would that look like?

Sometimes the creating takes longer and the xml:process starts even if the xml is not yet fully created.

I use Ubuntu 16.04 if it's relevant.

Comment: Are you just asking if you can add `php /var/www/html/artisan xml:process MyXML >> /var/log/xml-process.log 2>&1` to the bottom of your script? If so, the answer is yes. I would suggest adding the line as a starting point. You could also try running the command by itself interactively as the same user that runs the script.

Comment: Yes. I was asking exactly that. :-) I have no clue, what the rest of your comment means. Sorry, I am an absolute beginner. Can you explain that a bit in more detail? Maybe as an Answer, so I can mark it as the best answer...

Comment: The problem is that your question basically boils down to "can I run a command from a shell script" and the answer is "yes"! I was just suggesting you try running the `php` command separately from a terminal to see if it works, rather than adding it to the bottom of your script and waiting for the whole thing. If the two things are dependent on one another, it makes no sense for them to be scheduled separately.

Comment: The php command should be ran AFTER the exe finished its work and I have many of these, so I can't run it manually from terminal every time. So I think based on your answer, that it's the best if I add it at the end of the shell script. The php process works, because I run it regularly, just by crontab, not from the script, but it needs to be sure that the exe finished its work and from the crontab it was always just a guesswork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you are currently running two separately scheduled tasks from `cron`.

A shell script contains a series of commands, which are executed one by one in the order in which they appear, unless specified otherwise.

If your `php` command should always be executed after the `mono` command completes, then just add it to the bottom of that script and remove the separate `cron` entry:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/MyDirectory
mono MyApp.exe ./SpecificDirectory

# it may be necessary to change directory here
# (but it doesn't look like it, since you're using absolute paths)
php /var/www/html/artisan xml:process MyXML >> /var/log/xml-process.log 2>&1
```